# How do I convert an annotated PDF to an image?

Tags: cocoa

I have an annotated PDF and want to convert it to image. The pdf is successfully getting converted to an image but annotations are missing in the conversion.

This is the code:

```cpp
NSPDFImageRep *img = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:PdfFilePath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[img setCurrentPage:0];

NSImage *temp = [[NSImage alloc] init]; 
[temp addRepresentation:img]; 
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[temp TIFFRepresentation]]; 
NSData *finalData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil]; 
NSString *pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page1_%d.jpeg", 0]; 
NSString *imgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",@"/Users/Desktop/PDFImages", pageName];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:imgFilePath contents:finalData attributes:nil];
```

Is there a different way to store the annotated pdf to image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved using image lock and unlock feature.

```
     NSSize     pageBounds1;
    pageBounds1 = [page1 boundsForBox: [_pdfView displayBox]].size;
    NSImage *temp = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:pageBounds1];

    [temp lockFocus];
    [page1 drawWithBox:kPDFDisplayBoxMediaBox];
    [temp unlockFocus];

    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[temp TIFFRepresentation]]; 
    NSData *finalData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil]; 
    NSString *pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page1_%d.jpg", pageIndex]; 
    NSString *imgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",pathForImages, pageName];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:imgFilePath contents:finalData attributes:nil];
```